# Skip approval process step if individual has already approved a previous step

Tags: approval-process

We have logic in place where an user who is not coded as a manager needs their managers approval. Then if it's over a certain dollar value it moves on to a specific individual based upon the department being charged. If the users manager and the department being charged is the same person they ended up having to approve it twice in two separate steps.
Is there a way to detect if the individual for a given step has already approved a previous step and skip over it so they don't end up having to approve something twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can construct a formula field or populate a value on the object that meets this condition "If the users manager and the department being charged is the same person" then you could skip that step via the entry criteria.

Comment: good plan. forgot to give you credit. Thanks